# What is the difference between the words "dormant" and "latent"?

Tags: meaning, differences

It seems that they are interchangeable but I am having a hard time differentiating between the two.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a brief explanation of the difference between *latent* and *dormant* in James Fernald, *English Synonyms and Antonyms* (1914):

> That which is *latent* (from L. *lateo*, lie hidden) is *hidden* from ordinary observation (compare HIDE); as, *latent* powers; a *latent* motive; a disease is said to be *latent* between the time of its contraction and its manifestation. *Dormant* (from L. *dormio*, sleep) applies to the winter condition of hibernating animals, when they seem to sleep, or are even apparently lifeless; we speak of *dormant* energies (which have acted, and may yet again be aroused); a *dormant* volcano volcano; ...

*Webster's Dictionary of Synonyms* (1942) places *latent* and *dormant* in a larger group of related words that also includes *quiescent*, *potential*,and *abeyant*:

> **Latent**, **dormant**, **quiescent**, **potential**, **abeyant** (or **in abeyance**) agree in meaning not now manifesting its existence. **Latent** implies concealment and is applied to that which is present without showing itself; **dormant** usually suggests sleeping and is applied to that which is alive without manifesting activity; as, a *latent* talent; *latent* energy; a *dormant* plant or volcano. "The poet's gift of seeing the *latent* possibilities in everything he touched" (*[John Livingston] Lowes*). "Which power can never exercised by the people themselves, but must be be placed in the hands of agents, or lie dormant" (*Ch[ief] Just[ice John] Marshall*).

Fernald's example of a latent disease is apt because, even though the germs may be proliferating madly inside the infected person's body, there are no symptoms yet—and as a result, the presence of the disease is hidden. A dormant disease, in contrast, is one that a person has had in the past but that has ceased (at least temporarily) to be active—and yet may be reactivated under the right circumstances (as when the body's built-up immunity to it breaks down).

Answer (score 0):

Dormant refers to things not yet active, but with a chance to develop later, so like a bad gene in your body, that is waiting to be triggered by something.

> not active or developing now, but possibly active in the future

Latent can be used in the same meaning, but also as something that has been hidden, not just undeveloped.

> A feeling or quality that is latent exists now but is hidden or not yet developed.

Comment: Yes, because ‘dormant’ is derived from the Latin ‘dormire’ = to sleep and ‘latent’ is derived from ‘latere’ = to lie hid.  For some reason, ‘dormant’ is misderived from the 4th conjugation Latin verb.  Strictly, it ought to be ‘dormient’.  But then, derivers do not always follow strict rules.

Comment: So they can be used interchangeably? Can someone use them in sentences? For example: you couldn’t say “latent volcano” aka “inactive volcano,” because that isn’t the correct usage. I’m still pretty confused.

Comment: @Tuffy: "Dormant" was taken from French, not directly from Latin. In French, present participles are formed with *-ant* for verbs of all conjugation classes.

Comment: @sumelic Oops! Of course you are right.  Thanks for reminding me.